# Update if exists, destroy if empty, create if doesn't exist on array form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to update multiple records at once but coming to an issue with my validation for uniqueness scope.

When I create a record on a per-record-basis, it does what the title asks.  But with the array, it doesn't.

Why?
Because the params don't pass the ID of the nested attribute to update.

Example of param difference of updating on a per record vs array:

Mutli update:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"==", "shop_product_ids"=>["42"], "shop_product"=>{"shop_product_print_files_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"print_location_id"=>"1", "image_file_id"=>"2"}, "1"=>{"print_location_id"=>"2", "image_file_id"=>"2"}, "2"=>{"print_location_id"=>"3", "image_file_id"=>""}, "3"=>{"print_location_id"=>"4", "image_file_id"=>""}, "4"=>{"print_location_id"=>"5", "image_file_id"=>""}, "5"=>{"print_location_id"=>"6", "image_file_id"=>""}}}, "commit"=>"Edit Checked"}
```

1 Record Update:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"==", "shop_product"=>{... "shop_product_print_files_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"print_location_id"=>"1", "image_file_id"=>"1", "id"=>"145"}, "1"=>{"print_location_id"=>"2", "image_file_id"=>"", "id"=>"151"}, "2"=>{"print_location_id"=>"3", "image_file_id"=>""}, "3"=>{"print_location_id"=>"4", "image_file_id"=>""}, "4"=>{"print_location_id"=>"5", "image_file_id"=>""}, "5"=>{"print_location_id"=>"6", "image_file_id"=>""}},"id"=>"42"}, "commit"=>"Sync", "id"=>"42"}
```

On the one record update, it passes the shop_product_print_file ID in order to update.  On the multi, it doesn't and shouldn't.

Goal: To update if exists, create if it doesn't destroy if empty.  I need to somehow do what I do in the model `reject_if` in my controller but I am boggled on how to.

**Models:**

```
class PrintLocation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :shop_products, through: :shop_product_print_files
  has_many :shop_product_print_files
end

class ShopProductPrintFile < ApplicationRecord
  validates :shop_product, uniqueness: { scope: :print_location }
  belongs_to :shop_product
  belongs_to :print_location
  belongs_to :image_file
end

class ShopProduct < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :shop_product_print_files
  has_many :print_locations, through: :shop_product_print_files
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shop_product_print_files
  ...
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shop_product_print_files, reject_if: :reject_file, :allow_destroy => true


  def reject_file(attributes)
    if attributes[:image_file_id].blank?
      if attributes[:id].present?
        attributes.merge!({:_destroy => 1}) && false
      else
        true
      end
    end
  end
end

class ImageFile < ApplicationRecord
  # this is where users upload files to
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :shop_product_print_files
end
```

Controller methods handling this:

```
def edit_multiple
    @image_files = ImageFile.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    @shop_products = ShopProduct.find(params[:shop_product_ids])
    @shop_product = ShopProduct.new
    @shop_product.shop_product_print_files.build PrintLocation.all.map { |pl| { print_location: pl } }
  end

  def update_multiple
    @shop_products = ShopProduct.find(params[:shop_product_ids])
    @image_files = ImageFile.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    @shop_products.reject! do |shop_product|
        shop_product.update_attributes!(params[:shop_product].permit(:shop_product, shop_product_print_files_attributes: [ :id, :print_file, :print_location_id, :shop_product_id, :image_file_id ]).reject { |k,v| v.blank? })
    end
    if @shop_products.empty?
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      @shop_product = ShopProduct.new(params[:shop_product])
      render "edit_multiple"
    end
  end
```

When updating on a record-by-record basis, the `:reject_file` method handles my goal with the help of the SPPF passing through.  But When doing this with the array, no SPPF ID passes through which gives me the error:

```
> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Shop product print
> files shop product has already been taken):
```

Does anyone have any conclusions on how  I can accomplish this?

I am omitting the form to update array to keep this short as the parameters should explain it enough since what I need is most likely either a controller conditional statement to achieve my goal .

Comment: I think that you're misunderstanding the `reject!` method. What is does is iterate over the array, passing each element into the block, and return all the elements for which the block returns false. The way you're using it now seems like you're trying to set `@shop_products` to all of the records that couldn't be updated, except by using `update_attributes!` you're making it throw an error anyways. Also, is there a reason you're using `update_attributes` instead of just a normal `update`?

Comment: No reason, I actually followed a tutorial on this because I've never done it before,.  I did try using update(strong_params) with the same issue? I figured it would work the same way but didnt.  But yes.  To iterate my goal further, this is only for updating @shop_product nested_attributes only, really, the ShopProduct model shouldn't take any updates or changes, only the SPPF model should